# Flask DateTime bag

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I write blog with Flask and I have some problem with DataTime. I use a FlaskAdmin to create the post for blog but very offen I see that data and time of creating post are the same that for previous post. I don`t understand how fix this((((
[image]

time in flaskadmin generate automation

this my models

[image]

Upd:
I watch to server and see that time seted once when I start server and change only when server restarting, but I need start function datatime.now every time when I want create post)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM5Rs.png)

Comment: How about just running the datetime function by itself? Why would the issue be Flask Admin not just Python or your computer? How would we know if your other clocks aren't wrong?

Comment: i tried to monitor the server behavior. As you can see in the models there is a "created" field and it has a default value as a function of "datatime (nav)". I see that this function runs on the server starting and gives the field a single value that does not change until the server restarts. I need to run this function every time when I open a "create post" page

Comment: Okay, that doesn't answer my question. Flask does not seem to be the problem here. What does `datetime.now()` actually give you in a Python terminal? Maybe it doesn't change because you made the field a class variable? Rather than adding the timestamp as the post is actually being saved into the database? In other words, why do you need to show the field on the page at all?

Comment: finally I find a solution for my problem . I delete default value for "created" field in my models file and create a function that set up time for "created" field when somewhere creating exemplar of class Post from my models file. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is solution for me.
I remove a default value for field "created" and create nev function for class Post that set up a time for field "created" when somewhere creating exemplar of class Post
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRf5v.png)